# Loop causing unreachable breakpoints

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to replicate the Luhn algorithm in C++ but I'm having a problem. As you can see I have two for loops. In MSVC, if I place a break point in the second for loop, or even on the return MSVC will tell me that the break point will not be hit.

What is causing this problem?

```
int luhn_checksum(std::vector<int> cardnumber[NUMBER_OF_DIGITS - 1]) {
    //step 1: duouble every second number
    for (int i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_DIGITS; i + 2) {
        new_digits[i] = digits[i] * 2;
        if (new_digits[i] > 9) {
            //if the product is larger than 9 we will add the two numbers together
            //example: 9 * 2 = 18 so we will add 1 + 8 to get 9
            tmp1 += new_digits[i] % 10;
            new_digits[i] /= 10;
            tmp1 = 0;
        }
    }

    //step 2: sum all the values
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_DIGITS; ++i) {
        checksum += new_digits[i];
    }

    return checksum;
}
```

Comment: your first `for` loop's iteration portion should read `i += 2`, not `i + 2`

Comment: are you sure that this is right? `std::vector<int> cardnumber[NUMBER_OF_DIGITS - 1]` I think there are a number of logical errors here.

Comment: @RichardHodges I see what you mean. I was thinking that buy doing NUMBER_OF_DIGITS - 1 I would pass an array with positions up to 15, but instead I'm short of one position.

Comment: @user3084450 what you're actually doing is passing the address of 15 vectors of int, each vector may be any length you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first for loop you do not have increment 
so replace

```
for (int i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_DIGITS; i += 2)
```

if you want to increment by 2